# Upper bound on a norm of a vector w.r.t a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, matrix-norms

Suppose $\mathbf{z}_s \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for all $s\in\{1,\cdots,t \}$ such that $l\le \|\mathbf{z}_s \|\le L$. We define $\mathbf{V}_t = \sum_{s=1}^t  \mathbf{z}_s \mathbf{z}_s^\top + \lambda \mathbf{I}$ which is the design matrix in linear regression. I am wondering if it is positive to find an upper bound on $\|\mathbf{z}_t \|_{\mathbf{V}_t^{-1}}$ based on the value of $t$ and other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

A sharp upper bound is given by $\sqrt{\frac{L^2}{L^2+\lambda}}$. It is attained when $\|\mathbf z_t\|=L$ and $\mathbf z_t$ is orthogonal (with respect to the standard inner product) to all other $\mathbf z_j$s.

Let $Z\in\mathbb R^{d\times t}$ be the matrix whose $j$-th column, for each $j$, is equal to $\mathbf z_j$. By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $\mathbf z_t=(a,0,\ldots,0)^\top$ for some $a\in[l,L]$. Using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we see that the $(1,1)$-th element of $ZZ^\top+\lambda I$ is equal to $\big((ZZ^\top)_{11}+\lambda-p\big)^{-1}$ for some nonnegative number $p$. Therefore
$$
\|\mathbf z_t\|_{V_t^{-1}}
=\sqrt{\mathbf z_t^\top V_t^{-1}\mathbf z_t}
=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{(ZZ^\top)_{11}+\lambda-p}}
\le\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2+\lambda}}
\le\sqrt{\frac{L^2}{L^2+\lambda}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I am wondering if it is possible to find an upper bound based on the value of $t$? If not, is there any required assumption to find an upper bound dependent on $t$? Thanks

Comment: @Amin I have no idea, but you must take the structure of $Z$ into account, otherwise, as my answer shows, the best upper bound does not depend on $t$ if the only parameters are $l,L,\lambda$ and $t$.

Comment: Suppose $d$ is even and $\mathbf{z}_s=(\mathbf{x}_s,\mathbf{y}_s)$ where $l_x\le \|\mathbf{x}_s\|\le u_x$ and $l_y\le \|\mathbf{y}_s\| \le u_y$. In this case, it is possible to find an upper bound depending on $t$?

Comment: Yes, $t$ is the number of vectors $\mathbf{z}_s$. I think $\mathbf{V}_t^{-1}$ is a measure of variation. So, when we gather more information, uncertainty would decrease and I think it is expected that the norm of a vector with respect to $\mathbf{V}_t^{-1}$ will decrease. But, I don't know how to show it.

Comment: To add more info, $y$ is a linear function of $x$. So, these two vectors are not independent.

Comment: @Amin The $\mathbf z_s$ is your question is a column vector. Now it becomes a two-column matrix?

Comment: No, it is a concatenation of two vectors. $x,y \in R^{d/2}$

Comment: @Amin Then the answer remains unchange. The other $\mathbf z_j$s may still be orthogonal to $\mathbf z_t$. The upper bound in my answer, which is attainable and does not depend on $t$, is still valid.

Comment: Thanks. I was willing to find a bound depending on $t$ which might be related to information gathered over time. Appreciate